# Angular JS - ngRepeat in a Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use ngRepeat in a directive - but I really don't know how to do it.  Am I close?

Mowers is an array in my controller where this directive is used.

```
.directive('slider', function() {
return function() {
    template: '<slider><film><frame ng-repeat="mower in mowers">{{mower.series}}</frame></film></slider>';
    replace: true;
        scope: true;
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            // jquery to animate
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're close, but the syntax was off. and you need to assign something to `mowers` on your scope.

```
.directive('slider', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E', //to an element.
    template: '<film><frame ng-repeat="mower in mowers">{{mower.series}}</frame></film>',
    replace: true,
    scope: true, // creates a new child scope that prototypically inherits
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.mowers = [
               { series: 1 },
               { series: 2 },
               { series: 3 }
            ];
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you need to not reference `<slider>` in itself.

The above code also assumes you've made directives for `<film>` and `<frame>`.

Finally, if you wanted to pass the mowers array in from an external scope, you'd change your scope setting to this:

```
scope: {
   mowers: '='
}
```

And you could then set it like so:

```
<slider mowers="myMowers"></slider>
```

where `myMowers` is a variable on your controller or parent directive's scope.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I added that in there. Sorry, I tend to answer, then revise a lot.

Comment: @drew indicated that the controller scope has a `mowers` property, so I'm not sure why the link function is creating another one on the new child scope (which will hide/shadow the one on the parent scope), rather than just accessing the property on the parent scope.

Comment: I see what you mean. Good catch. In my mind he was doing a `scope:{}`.